# request not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

i am working on a web application using codeigniter.

i have a problem

when i request the controller like this

```
http://localhost:8080/Saffron/Product/137/test-text
```

every thing is ok but when i request the controller like this

```
http://localhost:8080/Saffron/Product/137/مهارت-های-آموزشی-در مطالعه
```

got this error

```
The requested URL /Saffron/Product/137/Ú©ØªØ§Ø¨-ØºÙ„Ø¨Ù‡-Ø¨Ø±-Ø§Ø¶Ø·Ø±Ø§Ø¨-Ø¯Ø±-Ù…Ø­ÛŒØ·-Ù‡Ø§ÛŒ-Ø¢Ù…ÙˆØ²Ø´ÛŒ was not found on this server.
```

i use this htaccess rules

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Saffron/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? [L]
</IfModule>
```

it work on server without error i have this problem on wamp locahost.where is the problem?

### UPDATE:

i finally found it:

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /Saffron/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Saffron/index.php [L]

work fine

Comment: You need to `encode-decode` your url

Comment: Is that a “classic” web server 404 error, or one issued by your Laravel system itself? Have you applied proper URL encoding in the place wherever you create/output this URL, or have you left this up to the browser?

Comment: it works on server.i have this problem on local wamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to your router file `application/config/routes.php`.

`$route['Product/(:num)/(:any)] = 'Product/$1/$2';`

I am assuming Saffron is your `base_url` directory.

Check below for more information:

[CI URI Route documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config 
 replace $config['base_url'] = ''; in code below how it will help you

```
if( (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') or defined('STDIN') )
{
    $config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
    $config['base_url'] .= "://". (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '127.0.0.1');
}
else
{
    $config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
    $config['base_url'] .= "://". (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '127.0.0.1');
    $config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
}

$config['secure_base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : '');
$config['secure_base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

For htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /folder name of your webapp/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i hav'nt any problem with index.php.i said my code works fine in server with no error.why i got error in localhost.i think i have problem with htaccess that does'nt handle persian characters